# Ignite C++. Can the following APIs be used?

Tags: c++, ignite

I was wondering if the following APIs are available in Ignite C++. And if they are not available, what would be a reasonable alternative to implementing the same things in a distributed project:

**IgniteAtomicSequence**

The objective of this API is to generate unique IDs for objects we're about to store. Is this API available in C++? If not what should we do as a replacement that relies only on the Ignite features available in the C++ API.-

**Continuous Queries**

Is this API available? It seems to be, but it's hard to understand what's the expected correct usage of it. I wonder if we can we use it to receive events on all updates as if we were using a pub sub system? Is this a fair usage of this API?

**Events**

Is this API usable through C++?

Comment: hi, perhaps this might have some https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/cppdoc/annotated.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently, only **Continuous Queries** are available. They can be used to receive cache-related events. The following types of events can be received:

- Cache item created;
- Cache item removed;
- Cache item updated;
- Cache item expired.

Here you can find [examples](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/continuous-queries).